# What is that process called in which we add water molecules to an ion to form a complex?

Tags: water, coordination-compounds

An example would be $\ce{[Fe(H2O)6]^2+}$ in which it has 6 water molecules associated with it. What is the process of adding these water molecules called?

Comment: What makes you think there exist some specific term for this particular kind of complexation?

Comment: Are you referring to "hydration"?

Comment: @ron thank you but i am confused is this called hydration ?Then what is  that called $\ce{FeSO4.5 H2O}$? The water of crystallization is also said to be a result of hydration reaction.Please clarify!!

Comment: $\ce{[Fe(H2O)6]^{2+}}$ and $\ce{[FeSO4(H2O)5]}$ are both examples of hydrated iron.  In the latter compound, one of the water ligands has been replaced by a sulphate ligand.

Comment: @ron what i am thinking is the first ion actually has coordinated $\ce{H2O}$  bonded to $\ce{Fe^2+}$ and in the second case the water of crystallisation is surrounding the compound FeSO4 by electrostatic attractions.

Comment: @Satyajeet Well, no; both are essentially the same thing only that one occurs in solution, the other has happened in crystallised form. If you're interested in the difference between hydration in crystals and hydration in solution, you should reword your question to reflect that.

Answer (score 2):

I believe it is normally just called "addition of water".
There is also the term "hydration" but this can also refer to the addition of water to alkenes or alkynes which forms alcohols (in the case of alkene; I am not sure about alkynes).
For example, $$\ce{CH2=CH2 \text{(ethene/alkene)} + H2O -> CH3CH2OH \text{(ethanol/alcohol)}}$$

I personally think "addition of water" is just fine to use and people will get what you are saying.

Comment: I would definitely use 'hydration'.